# Probability of 4 people picking the same number

Tags: probability

**Question**: Say we have four people who are to choose a number randomly from {1,2,3,4,5}. What is the probability they all pick the same number?

**Attempt** (apparently wrong): The sample space has $5^4$ elements, and the number of times that they have the same number is whether they all choose 1, choose 2 ,....,choose 5, which happens only 5 times, so the probability should be:$\frac{5}{5^4}=\frac{1}{5^3}$.

Comment: Why is this wrong? The first person can take any number, the other 3 have 1/5 chance of picking the same number. This multiplies and results in your answer.
Unless you have a different distribution (other than uniform). Is this the complete problem that was given to you?

Comment: @Pieter21 Yeah, it might not have been the most reliable site though as I'm having contradictions with a lot of their results, some of which are elementary probability qs